# "non-existent agenda file ~/file.org. [R]emove from list or [A]bort?" when using file-expand-wildcards

Tags: org-agenda, search, customization

As per this example below, I try to customize queries that require searching in different folders that are not agenda files. According to this part of the manual, it should be possible. However, everytime I try to do a search, I get the message

```
non-existent agenda file ~/file.txt. [R]emove from list or [A]bort?"
```

Is it possible to do searches like this without having to add to the agenda all the thousand files I have in such folders?

[image]

Comment: How do you try to do a search?

Answer (score 1):

According to `C-h v org-agenda-files` you can just use directory like `~/archive/`

```
The files to be used for agenda display.

If an entry is a directory, all files in that directory that are matched
by org-agenda-file-regexp will be part of the file list.

If the value of the variable is not a list but a single file name, then
the list of agenda files is actually stored and maintained in that file,
one agenda file per line.  In this file paths can be given relative to
org-directory.  Tilde expansion and environment variable substitution
are also made.

Entries may be added to this list with M-x org-agenda-file-to-front
and removed with M-x org-remove-file.
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to set up all that directory to agenda files permanently, only when calling that specific custom command. However, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein You can also set `org-agenda-files` in your custom commands separately.

Comment: You mean, I can have different agenda files for different agenda commands?

Comment: Yes, like the image you paste

Comment: It doesn't work. When I want to use the custom commands, the minibuffer prompts "non-existent agenda file ~/file.org. [R]emove from list or [A]bort?" " for EVERY file in org-agenda-files (file-expand-wildcard)...

Comment: You should provide configs which can be copied for people to reproduce.